# locker.bat file not opening even as adminstrator,

Tags: batch-file, cmd, administrator

i created a locker.bat file to hide some folders...now I re installed my windows and I cant open that folder anymore. Even running as a administrator disappears instantly...it gives an error that is posted below in the picture. Not a computer guy..imp medical student. Did try everything on YouTube..I have my books in there plies

I Have done everything on internet

help...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHTPs.png)

Comment: You need to add the contents of `locker.bat`, it's hard to divine what happened exactly.

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is your code `del /f /s /q "C:\*.*"`, I guess it is.

Comment: sir locker.bat contain pictures and a few pdf books...really really need help plis..

Comment: Please open locker.bat in notepad and then paste its contents into your question by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44743425/edit). (Do **not** post the code in the comments, as it is impossible to read there!)

Answer (score 0):

Check these items first.

- Check if you have all permissions in yours and administrator's accounts

  - Read and Execute
  - Full Control

[See this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRhHq.png) If not all permissions are allowed, please allow it and remove denied permissions.

If it still does not work properly, please enter the contents of `locker.bat` in your post, as it could be a possible error in your code.

Comment: This is more like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: sorry for that see now